# How can I add support for class name autocomplete in my TypeScript based library?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have coded a simple but useful library called CliSpinner.https://github.com/AxeriDev/CliSpinner

The problem is, VScode has typescript class autocomplete but it never finds mine.
I export the class inside of CliSpinner.ts like so:

```js
class CliSpinner { ... }

const cliSpinner = new CliSpinner();
export default cliSpinner;
```

when I start typing CliSpi or cliSpi I never get a mathcing result to import.
How do other librarys and packages achive this. Chalk is a js lib but it still has this.
When I start typing chal, chalk comes up and I can click to import it.

Comment: NOTE: I have all the d.ts files and map files

Answer (score 1):

To address the issue you're facing with VSCode's autocomplete not recognizing `CliSpinner` for import, the root cause lies in how you're exporting from your `CliSpinner.ts`. Currently, you're exporting an instance of the class, which IDEs like VSCode typically don't autocomplete in the same way they do for class names, functions, etc.

Here's a solution tailored to different scenarios depending on your intention:

###### If You Want to Export the Class:

Change your export to directly export the class itself. This is more in line with common practices and what you'd typically expect an import statement to bring in:

```js
export class CliSpinner { ... }
```

By doing so, when consumers of your library want to use `CliSpinner`, they can easily import the class and instantiate it as needed:

```js
import { CliSpinner } from 'path/to/CliSpinner';
const cliSpinner = new CliSpinner();
```

###### If You Prefer to Export a Singleton Instance:

Sometimes, the goal is to provide a single, shared instance of a class that can be used throughout an application, akin to a singleton. You can still achieve this while allowing for the direct import of the class type when needed:

```js
class CliSpinner { ... }

const cliSpinner = new CliSpinner();

export { CliSpinner, cliSpinner as default };
```

With this approach, you're offering the best of both worlds: the ability for users to import and use the singleton instance directly and the option to instantiate new `CliSpinner` objects if their use case requires it.

###### Additional Tip:

Ensure that your TypeScript configuration is set up to generate `.d.ts` (declaration) files and that these are correctly included in your package. This setup is crucial for aiding IDEs like VSCode in providing accurate autocomplete suggestions. You can ensure declaration files are generated by adding the following to your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Just make sure the paths reflect your project's structure.

After making these adjustments, you might also need to restart the TS server in VSCode (`TypeScript: Restart TS server` command) or even VSCode itself to see the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're exporting an instance of CliSpinner, not the class itself. When you type CliSpi or cliSpi, VS Code is looking for exported classes or functions with those names, but it won't find any because you're only exporting an instance.

```
export default class CliSpinner { ... }
```

If you want to export the class itself, you should do:

```
import CliSpinner from 'cli-spinner-package';
const cliSpinner = new CliSpinner();
```

Then, you can import it in another file like this:
If you want to keep the instance export but also have the class available for import, you can do:

```
class CliSpinner { ... }

const cliSpinner = new CliSpinner();
export { CliSpinner };
export default cliSpinner;
```

Then, you can import the class like this:

```
import { CliSpinner } from 'cli-spinner-package';
```

And the instance like this:

```
import cliSpinner from 'cli-spinner-package';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jsconfig.json or tsconfig.json files. If you have configuration you cant try to edit "include" field as involve "d.ts" files.

```
"include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
```